# Alternatives to Bouncy Castle java library for PKCS7 encryption/signing?

Tags: java, encryption, pkcs#7

We've always used the BouncyCastle library, I'm being asked if there are other viable alternatives, either open source or not. Or is the BouncyCastle library already the best one to use?

Comment: Can you post a code sample? I think you should be able to use stock `SunJCE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [classpathx](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/classpathx/).  However, from experience I would say that Bouncy Castle is definitely the best.